# How do I access variable outside of a JSX component in typescript/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a render function here:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="cashflow-entry">

                    {
                        Object.entries(this.state.cashflowToPost).map(([k, v], _) => {
                            let inputType = 'text'
                            if (typeof v == 'boolean') {
                                inputType = 'checkbox'
                            }
                            return (
                                <label>
                                    Asset {k}:
                                    <input type={inputType} name='name' onChange={(event: any) => {
                                        this.setState({ cashflowToPost: { ...this.state.cashflowToPost, k: event.target.value } });
                                    }}></input>
                                </label>
                            )
                        })
                    }

                </div>

            </form>

        )
```

I want to access the `k` value inside the returned jsx. But it just saves it as the field `'k'` instead of the string value `k` has when mapping over the list.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you want to use the value of k as a object key, you can use this syntax: `[k]: event.target.value`

Comment: `K` is the dynamic key so, for the property key in the object, you need to wrap that key with `[]`